# Java: Wrong JSON schema when using javax.json.JsonObject and the RESTEasy embedded server

Tags: java, json, jackson, resteasy

I am writing tests using TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer. I got the JSON serialization working but the format is different from when I deploy the code on an WildFly 10 application server.

The test JSON is generated via javax.json.Json. If I just serialize an object I don't have this problem.

```
@GET
@Path("/testgroup")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getTestGroup() String filter) {

    JsonObject jsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                 .add("id", 1L)
                 .add("label", "TestGroup1").build();

    return Response.ok(jsonObject).build();
}
```

The JSON from the **TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer**:

```
{
    "id": {
        "integral": true,
        "valueType": "NUMBER"
    },
    "label": {
        "chars": "TestGroup1",
        "string": "TestGroup1",
        "valueType": "STRING"
    }
}
```

The JSON from the same code deployed on the **WildFly**:

```
{
     id: 1,
     label: "TestGroup1"
}
```

The Maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.1.0-AP</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Test Class:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void init() {
    scaleRecource = new ScaleRecource();
    scaleRecource.masterDataService = new MasterDataService();

    TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer server = new TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer();
    server.setPort(1234);
    server.getDeployment().getResources().add(scaleRecource);
    server.start();

    RestAssured.port=1234;
}

@Test
public void testGetGroup() {

    given()
      .when().get(rootPath + "/testgroup")
      .then().log().body().statusCode(200);

}
```

Are the Maven dependencies wrong or how do I configure the serialization with the RESTeasy embedded server?

**Edit**: If I remove the org.glassfish.javax.json dependency. I do get an error that the class org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl can not be found. But a serialization without using the the JsonObject does still work:

```
return Response.ok(new CodedEntry("code1", "testgroup")).build();
```

Also this type of serialization does result in a expected JSON even when using the TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer.

Is there another implementation for the javax.json.JsonObject interface present on the WildFly?

Comment: How did you generate this JSON?

Comment: @Henry Is that important? I don't want to change the JSON generation just for testing as it does work fine on the target application server. But I can add the code.

Comment: "Is that important?": yes. We can't help if we don't know what you are doing.

Comment: post the code that serializes the JSON, dependencies are used to load the application

Comment: As i see you need the values but you get from the service the metadata of the JSON obejct. Change your code to return you the actual data and not the metadata.

Comment: @Σωτήρης Ραφαήλ I want the same serialization that is configured for the WildFly in my embedded server test. I do not want to change the serialization code.

Comment: @Henry I added the code. I can add the code of the test class as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspeced the problem was a wrong dependency.

I had to replace the dependency

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
     <version>1.1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-json-p-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

As this has the json-p implementation that is bundled with WildFly: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/userguide/html/json-p.html

This is only needed for the implementation of the javax.json.JsonObject interface from the [Java EE 7 JSON-P API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsonp002.htm).

I had initially added the wrong one because I got the error that the class org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl can not be found.